# Jshell - Why System.out.printf is populating this answer

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

Can any one help me to figure out the mistake i am doing. The expected is to print `4%2` as 0. I had tried both ways.

[image]

Comment: First mistake: asking why code doesn't work but not showing the code. Second mistake: showing the error message as a screen capture instead of text.

Comment: Third error, not embedding the picture in the question but hosting it elsewhere.

Comment: If only you could have tried to look for the available methods and their documentation in jshell itself. `jshell> System.out.printf(
Signatures:
PrintStream PrintStream.printf(String format, Object... args)
PrintStream PrintStream.printf(Locale l, String format, Object... args)

<press tab again to see documentation>` (double tab in MacOS after typing the method name)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a method call System.out.printf(int) with integer parameter 
so use print or println

```
 System.out.print(4%2);
```

then the out put is 0